# python class inheritance order

Tags: python, inheritance, declaration

I have a file test.py

```
class A(B):
  def display(self):
      print ("In A")

class B:
  def display(self):
    print ("In B")
```

I get the following error while run it
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "/Users/praveen/Documents/test.py", line 1, in <module>
   class A(B):
NameError: name 'B' is not defined
```

But if I change the order of declaration, It runs without any errors

```
class B:
  def display(self):
    print ("In B")

class A(B):
  def display(self):
      print ("In A")
```

Can anyone explain in detail why this weird error happens?

Comment: Because Python won't know what `B` means until you've defined it. It's not really that weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because python gets interpreted Top-To-Bottom. In the line where you define `class A(B)` in your first example, `class B` was not yet read by python.

In your second example, `B` is already known in the line `class A(B)`. That's why it runs.

Answer (score 2):

simple: when python evaluates `class A(B):` B is still undefined,

unfortunately python has no class prototypes (or forward declarations)

but this is only a problem if you have 2 classes that explicitly need to point to each other.